# Why is the product of path homotopy classes not defined sometimes?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Munkres says on pg. 346 that the set of path homotopy classes does not aways form a group under the operation $*$ because the product of two path homotopy classes is not always defined.

What does this mean? Does this mean $[f]*[g]\neq [f*g]$? Or does this mean something else? Could someone please give an example?

Answer (score 2):

The product of paths, and thus of homotopy classes of paths, is only defined when the terminal point of the first path is the initial point of the seconds.

Comment: Yes. But can we say that for any two paths $f$ and $g$ for which $f*g$ is defined, $[f]*[g]$ is aso defined? And is it also not true that $[f]*[g]\neq[f*g]$?

Answer (score 2):

The path homotopy equivalence relation applies to any two paths $f,g$ *with the same start and end points*, that is, $f(0)=g(0)$ and $f(1)=g(1)$. Also, the path concatenation function $f*g$ (and the equivalence class analogue $[f]*[g]$) is only defined when the start of the second path matches the end of the first, i.e. $f(1)=g(0)$. Thus if $\pi_{A,B}$ is the set of paths from $A$ to $B$ quotient with the path homotopy relation, then if $A\ne B$, $\pi_{A,B}$ is not a group under $*$ because for any $f\in\pi_{A,B}$, $f*f$ is not defined.

Comment: Yes. But can we say that for any two paths $f$ and $g$ for which $f*g$ is defined, $[f]*[g]$ is aso defined? And is it also not true that $[f]*[g]\neq[f*g]$?

Comment: If $f*g$ is defined and $f'\sim f$, $g'\sim g$, then $f'*g'\sim f*g$, so $[f]*[g]$ is defined and equals $[f*g]$.

Comment: But all paths in $[f]$ have the terminal points of $f$. Similarly, all paths in $[g]$ have the terminal points of $g$. Hence, $[f]*[g]$ has three fixed points: $f(0), f(1)=g(0)$, and $g(1)$. However, the paths in $[f*g]$ need not have the fixed point $f(1)$. How is it then possible that $[f]*[g]=[f*g]$|

Comment: And I don't think your previous comment is accurate. It just implies that $[f]*[g]$ is well defined, and not that it equals $[f*g]$

Comment: @algebraically_speaking The function $*$ applied to equivalence classes is *by definition* the class of all paths equivalent to $f*g$, that is, $[f]*[g]=[f*g]$ is a definition. What remains is to check that it is well-defined, which is, if $[f]=[f']$ and $[g]=[g']$ then $[f*g]=[f'*g']$, which was my previous statement. But the definition of the 'lifted' function $*$ that acts on equivalence classes is separate from the $*$ that acts on paths and has its own definition.

Comment: As you say, for any $f'\in[f]$, $g'\in[g]$, $(f'*g')(1/2)=(f*g)(1/2)$. However, $[f]*[g]$ is not just $\{f'*g':f'\in[f],g'\in[g]\}$ but rather the set of all paths equivalent to the ones in this set, which frees the point at $1/2$ up to be other things. Remember that the definition is really just $[f]*[g]=[f*g]$, when it makes sense.

Comment: The word **groupoid** occurs on p. 326 of Munkres' book, but he does not mention any of the algebra of groupoids, which can be found for example in Higgins' book "Categories and groupoids",  published in **1971**, and now downloadable from http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/7/tr7abs.html